# My app isn't appearing in my app drawer even though it has installed

Tags: android, debugging, manifest, drawer

Why won't the app appear in the app drawer?  It says in the App Manager that it is installed but I can't seem to open the actual app as it isn't in the app drawer.  It doesn't automatically open it up once it's installed either.

Here is what is said when I choose to run on my phone (which is on Jellybean).  It says the same thing when I install it to an emulator.

```
    [2012-09-19 16:20:24 - TheForeverAloneQuiz] Performing sync
    [2012-09-19 16:20:24 - TheForeverAloneQuiz] Automatic Target Mode: Several compatible targets. Please select a target device.
    [2012-09-19 16:20:28 - TheForeverAloneQuiz] Uploading TheForeverAloneQuiz.apk onto device '001988a8094d8e'
    [2012-09-19 16:20:28 - TheForeverAloneQuiz] Installing TheForeverAloneQuiz.apk...
    [2012-09-19 16:20:31 - TheForeverAloneQuiz] Success!
    [2012-09-19 16:20:31 - TheForeverAloneQuiz] /TheForeverAloneQuiz/bin/TheForeverAloneQuiz.apk installed on device
    [2012-09-19 16:20:31 - TheForeverAloneQuiz] Done!
```

Here's the android manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mikenning.foreveralonequiz"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Introduction"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_introduction" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INTRO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".QuestionOne"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_introduction" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUESTIONONE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Result"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_introduction" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESULTS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />         
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Anything I'm doing wrong?

**SIDENOTE**  I also get errors saying that I do not need permission for the activities categorised as 'DEFAULT'.  Could this be to do with it?  I need it for the startActivity() in one of my clases so is it really not required?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should name your custom Intent actions to your own package. Example `com.mikenning.foreveralonequiz.INTRO` instead of using `android.intent.action.INTRO`. This will prevent you inadvertently using a genuine Android Intent action which may give unpredictable results.

Comment: @Squonk; so should I remove the intent filter and instead of using "android.intent.action.QUESTIONONE" in the startActivity() thingy, I use "com.mikenning.foreveralonequiz.QuestionOne"?

Comment: Normally you only need the `MAIN` `LAUNCHER` entries for your main `Activity` and don't need any `<intent-filter>` elements for any other `Activity` unless you want them to be accessible to other (3rd party) apps. The normal way to start an `Activity` from your own app is to use an explicit `Intent`. Example `Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionOne.class);` then call `startAcivity(i);`.

Comment: @Squonk; I tried doing that.  I did; "Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionOne.class);" and got "The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<QuestionOne>) is 
 undefined" as an error.

Comment: Sorry, from inside an anonymous class such as your `OnClickListener` instead of `this` you need to fully qualify it with the 'outside' class. Example `Intent i = new Intent(Introduction.this, QuestionOne.class);`

Comment: @Squonk; I'm now getting a force close error on my activity start.  It is mentioned in the android manifest too.  I'm starting a new question on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that introduction is your first Activity. You need to add another action to it, like in the following code:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Introduction"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_introduction" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INTRO" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Why do I need to add another action?

Comment: Activities with the MAIN action, and the LAUNCHER category are displayed in launchers. I don't know why you have the INTRO action, but I guess you had it for a reason. Since you were missing the MAIN action, Android did not know that you wanted this Activity to be displayed in the launcher

Comment: You are a life saver.  Thank you.  This has been added to my knowledge bank >.< I guess the INTRO action is unnecessary.  Be easier if I remove it, me thinks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is solved question, but this solution did not work for me and I wanted to share my solution here.

I was trying to add deep link support to my app, And in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) the

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="gizmosexample"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I added those intent filters to my launcher activity and after app drawer stopped showing the app icon in the launcher.

So if [@RaghavSood's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12499265/2296787) above did not work, try to remove those filters or any other custom filters from the launcher activity's filters.